# int not increasing

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement, int

i have a nested nested (double nested) if statement inside a method which is called several times. each time i add one to the int (count) inside that if statement. here it is:

```
      if (currentString) {

            count += 1;
            NSLog(@"%i" , count);
        }
```

I logged it and it logged few times but the number was ALWAYS 1:

```
    2012-01-27 12:29:26.127 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
   2012-01-27 12:29:26.128 Appletini[479:10a03] 1       
   2012-01-27 12:29:26.132 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
   2012-01-27 12:29:26.134 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
    2012-01-27 12:29:26.138 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
  2012-01-27 12:29:26.139 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
   2012-01-27 12:29:26.143 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
    2012-01-27 12:29:26.143 Appletini[479:10a03] 1
```

count is an instance variable:

```
 @interface RSSItem : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

   int count;
```

}

any ideas???

Comment: your code is not sufficient to look for the reason. Try providing more code.

Comment: yes... show where count is declared and how that method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you meant to make "count" be `static` so it retains its value, but you forgot so it is just a normal local variable.

Comment: thank you
i have put static int count; in my implementation file

Answer (score 1):

`count` is likely local to the method. perhaps you meant to make `count` an instance variable? at any rate -- more code would help if you want a more specific response.

Comment: yes it is an instance variable